# Issue in creating Angular Docker Image with VSTS Pipeline

Tags: angular, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I am creating a VSTS pipeline for creating a Docker Image for Angular Application. I am using Agent pool as "Hosted Windows Container". I am getting the below error:

*Step 1/5 : FROM nginx:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1*

I have tried with below dockerfile entries:

1. FROM nginx
   COPY ./dist   /usr/share/nginx/html
   EXPOSE 80 443
2. FROM node:8-alpine as builder
   RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git

With both of them, I am getting same issues. I am suspecting it to be agent pool I have selected. Can someone confirm and what do I need to do to get this working in a Windows Container?

Comment: I got the same error :/

Comment: It's wired, some images like `hello-world` and `mongo` are working, and some are not.

Comment: I tried it with Linux as build agent and it works perfectly. But I would like to create it with Windows Container agent.

Comment: I think because you try build linux containers in docker for windows, there is a feature to turn on for enable that and I know to do it only in the UI...

Comment: Yes @ShaykiAbramczyk, you are right .... but i was not able to get a Windows container in dockers for windows in Angular .......

Comment: do you need nginx and node windows containers?

Comment: Yes! that would be great !

Comment: for node: `stefanscherer/node-windows`, for nginx: `e2eteam/nginx:1.15-alpine-1803`. note: this is **not** official images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the container image. Using the proper images *node: stefanscherer/node-windows, for nginx: e2eteam/nginx:1.15-alpine-180* as mentioned by @Shayki Abramczyk fixed the issue!